# How to make HTML lists wrap around floated content

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

Let's say I have an HTML figure floated left with text wrapping around it:

```
<figure style="float:left">…</figure>
<p>stuff</p>
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>
<dl>
  <dt>foo</dt>
  <dd>bar</dd>
</dl>
```

That's straightforward; the figure will float to the left, and the paragraph list will wrap around the figure on the right.

The bulleted list will look odd, though; the bullets won't be aligned with the paragraph content above it. And for the definition list `<dl>`, both the `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements are flush left, even if my stylesheet gives the `<dd>` a left margin, for example

The reason appears to be that floating an element doesn't make the containers wrap around it, but only *the container content*. So the `<ul>` isn't wrapping, but only the content inside it. So the `<p>` and the `<ul>` boxes actually extends clear to the left, *through* the floated figure, and only the content is wrapped to the right. Thus the `<dl>` left margin is relative to the left of the page and, since the space for the float is much more than the requested left margin, no extra margin is added after the content is wrapped.

Now it seems I can add a simple fix that will magically make this look better on my sample pages:

```
ul, ol, dl {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Basically this prevents margin-merging and essentially makes *the containers themselves* wrap around the figure. In other words, it prevents the float from being merged with their margins. And it looks just like I expect!

But… this seems to easy, and a bit wrong. Why wouldn't I apply this to `<p>` as well for example? What problems will this cause in the future? If I add some background color somewhere, will this cause problems if the `<p>` has a margin that extends through the float, but the lists do not?

To summarize, what's the best way to make lists look correct when they wrap around a float, and will using `overflow: auto` cause any unintended consequences?

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul, ol, dl,dd {
/*   overflow: auto; */
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
ul li{
    /*set position for li style*/
    /*list-style-position: inside;*/
    /*list-style-position: outside; */
    /* or for remove li style */
    list-style: none;

}
.clearfix:after{
  clear:both;
  content:"";
  display:block;
}
.float-right{
  float:right;
}
.float-left{
  float:left;
}
.wrapper{
  background:red;
  width:300px;
}
.wrapper-detail{
  background:blue;
  width:calc(100% - 100px);/* .wrapper's width - figure's with */
}
figure{
  width:100px;
  margin:0;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
  <figure class="float-left">…</figure>
  <div class="wrapper-detail float-right">
    <p>stuff</p>
    <ul>
      <li>foo</li>
      <li>bar</li>
    </ul>
    <dl>
      <dt>foo</dt>
      <dd>bar</dd>
    </dl>  
  </div>
</div>
```